# How is the ionic project closed?

Tags: ionic-framework

I'm a MacBook user.
How can I close the project from the terminal?

When I go directly from the terminal, the project is reset. What should I do?

Comment: What do you mean by reset? Data loss or refresh?

Answer (score 0):

press     `fn + c`  it will stop the app.

Comment: The project has been reset.